# how to make first character to be number and second character to be letter in edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, character

I want to make first character to be numeral and second character to be letter.
I tried like this but it disallows letters totally.

```
public static InputFilter[] myfilter=new InputFilter[]{
        new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int i=start;i<end;i++){
                    if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(0))){
                        return "";
                    }

                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
```

//////

```
 edittext1.setFilters(myfilter);
```

I want to make first character to be only number and second character only letters. how can I do that?

Comment: `return null;` return source; ? And you are not using `i` in your for loop. So what is it.....

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a TextWatcher and add constraints for the input?

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(charSequence.length() == 1 && !Character.isDigit(charSequence.charAt(0))){
                    editText.setText("");
                }

                if(charSequence.length() == 2 && !Character.isAlphabetic(charSequence.charAt(1))){
                    editText.setText(editText.getText().subSequence(0,1));
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you it worked